# Distribution of the ratio of two shifted generalized gamma random variable

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, gamma-distribution, beta-distribution

$X \sim \mathrm{GG}\left(p,d,\theta_{1},\mu\right)$ where $p$ is power, $d$ is shape, $\theta_1$ is scale and $\mu$ is location parameter. Also Consider $Y \sim \mathrm{GG}\left(p,d,\theta_{2},\mu\right)$ where $p$ is power, $d$ is shape, $\theta_2$ is scale and $\mu$ is location parameter.

Where,

$f(x;θ_1,d,p,\mu)=\left(\frac{p}{\theta_1^d}\right)(x−\mu)^{d−1}e^{−[(x−μ)/θ_1]^p}/Γ(d/p)\;\;\; ,x>\mu\;\mbox{ and } p,d,\theta_1>0$

What is the distribution of $\;Z=\frac{X}{Y}$?

All the papers I read so far only have the case without location parameter. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: What does $GG$ mean?

Comment: Generalized Gamma distribution.:) sorry

Comment: This may help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution

Comment: My comment was a suggestion to add an indicator function when  defining the density...

Comment: So , if I don't have location parameter, this ratio will be generalized beta prime distribution according to http://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cmb/v10/cmb1967v10.0463-0465.pdf. Do you think is it correct to claim that it is Generalized Beta Prime distribution with location parameter $\mu$ According to http://threeplusone.com/FieldGuide.pdf page 108?